# How to make button call a method from different scene in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new in swift programming.
I created a simple web app with simple sidebar, I'm using [SideMenu](https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu) for sidebar, and [DZNWebViewController](https://github.com/dzenbot/DZNWebViewController) for webview library.

The screenshot below

[Project Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fp09P.png)

I'm gonna make an action to call a method from `dashboard` button from sidebar scene. But there is no action when i try to create the action. Anybody help me, how to make an action to call a method from different scene?

Comment: you can use notification or delegate to solve your issue

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to handle this, the most common and used is to apply a Notification observer in your Controller in which you will receive the action.

```
//This line is used to suscribe to the notification, usually goes in viewDidLoad
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(actOnSpecialNotification), name: Notification.Name("someNotKey"), object: nil)
    //Function to fire when not is posted
    func actOnSpecialNotification() {
            //here! I've heard the notification!!!
        }
```

And you fire the notification in any other controller from your app:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("someNotKey"), object: self)
```

Further info:

[Fundamentals of Notifications in Swift](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2014/10/08/fundamentals-of-nsnotificationcenter-in-swift/)

[NotificationCenter class](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter)